# Is there a way to replace existing values with NaN

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm experimenting with the algorithms in **iPython** Notebooks and would like to know if I can replace the existing values in a dataset with `Nan` (about 50% or more) at random positions with each column having different proportions of `Nan` values.

I'm using the Iris dataset for this experimentation to see how the algorithms work and which one works the best.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: Can you post your dataset?

Comment: @chriz [link](http://depositfiles.com/files/lamp9yxa7)

I've uploaded the dataset

Answer (score 0):

There is a `replace` function in python. 
[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778748/how-to-use-replace-in-python)